# Probability distribution in 7th steps

Tags: probability-distributions, markov-chains, markov-process

Let's assume that there is a markov chain with a transition matrix $P$:
$\begin{bmatrix}
 0  &0  &0  &\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0&  \frac{1}{2}& \frac{1}{2} & 0\\ 
 0&  0&  \frac{1}{2}& 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0\\ 
 \frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3}\\ 
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$
Write probability distribution after seven steps assuming that inital vector is: $\bar{p}(0)=(0,0,0,1,0,0)$

So my goal is to get $\bar{p}(7)=(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4},x_{5},x_{6})$
according to the matrix I can say that $\bar{p}(7)=(x_{1},x_{2},0,0,0,\frac{1}{3})$ because, there is no way to go from state $4$ to states $5,4,3$. I have a little trouble with $x_{1},x_{2}$, but I can do that in two ways.

**First**: I can raise first and second column of the matrix to the power of seven and use: $\bar{p}(7)= \bar{p}(0) \cdot P^{7}$

**Second**: I can use: $\bar{p}(n)= \bar{p}(n-1) \cdot P$, and find $\bar{p}(1),\bar{p}(2),..,\bar{p}(6)$ and count it from $\bar{p}(7)=\bar{p}(6) \cdot P$

I think that there is much simpler solution that my approaches and I would be very grateful to show me how to do that quicker.
[image]

Comment: By symmetry, $x_1=x_2$. But $x_6$ is not equal to $1/3$, rather it is the chance of being absorbed at state $6$ at after either 1,3,5, or 7 transitions.

Answer (score 0):

You must raise $P$ to the power 7. This is not as easy as you seem to think. For instance, state 4 does not go to states 5,4,3 directly, but it can go indirectly after many steps.

Your matrix has some particularities. No state goes into state 3; state 7 is isolate. But this is not enough.

I have computed $P^7$ using Maple, and the answer is horrible.

Comment: So the only way to solve the problem is to compute $P^{7}$ ?

Comment: The general solution is taking $P^7$. For very special situations there may be shortcuts. I don't see that in your problem.

Comment: @BrianR Yes, there is a shortcut if you follow my hint.

Comment: From $S4$ I can go to $S2$ directly, it gives me: $2 \cdot (\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3})$ times two because I can go from $S4$ to $S1$ and ultimately to $S2$, but there is a possibility to go from $S4$ to $S2$ thorugh $S5$ so it gives me: $\frac{1}{3} \cdot (\frac{1}{2})^{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot ( \frac{1}{2})^{4} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3}$ count it, and it supposed to be $x_{1},x_{2}$ ?